# Reference to Hadith about a man who will be with Muhammad ﷺ in Jannah?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, source-identification, reference-request

Bismillah. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Sayyidil-Mursalin wa 'ala 'Alihi wa Sahbihi Ajma'in.

---

I can't find the hadith about a man who will be, allegedly, with Rasulullah ﷺ in Jannah. The Hadith tells a story about a man who in a dream sees Rasulullah ﷺ and Rasulullah ﷺ informs him about a person who will be in Jannah with him for a certain deed. The man wakes up and goes to find that person to find out what kind of deed he committed. The rest of the story reveals following:

That person, Rasulullah ﷺ informed about in the dream, gets married with a woman and finds out that the woman has committed Zina before marriage. So, she is not chaste, she is not virgin. But despite this, the person decides to hide this fact in order to save the woman from rumors (and punishment).

The conclusion of the story is that the person, who hid the Zina of the woman he married to, will be in Jannah with Rasulullah ﷺ. This is the deed which was informed by Rasulullah ﷺ in the dream.

**Anyone knows such hadith?**

Assalmu alaikum wa rahmatullahi wa barakatuh.

---

P.S. Tafseer of the hadith also needed.

Comment: Is this hadith from a shi'a or sunni source? Do you have any further information?

Comment: It must be Sunni source

Comment: `Do you have any further information?` The Hadith must contain words like "mosque", "Imam".

Comment: But I am not sure

Comment: @Medi1Saif, i remember reading something like this from the works of Al-Alusi a long time ago. if i remember correctly, it was a story the imam related and not a hadith. to find the exact report, will take some time.

Comment: @ahmad nazeem, that is possible.

Comment: The way you worded it, it does not seem like you are talking about the companions hearing something from the Prophet. Seems the Prophet was only in the dream. So, I doubt it would be considered a hadith or be in hadith collections.

Comment: There's also a logical issue. How do we know the man married someone who committed Zina if he never revealed to anyone she committed Zina?

Comment: @TheZ this is a story narrated by mahmud al-alusi in his tafsir. its about an imam seeing a dream of the prophet ﷺ, in which he is told that his neighbor will be in jannah with the prophet ﷺ. so he asks his neighbor what might be the reason and he reveals that when he got married his wife was pregnant with zina but he hid that from the world as she has repented. i am not able to locate the exact source yet as the tafsir of al-alusi is huge (30 volumes). hope someone can benefit from this comment and provide a detailed answer, in sha Allah.

Comment: @The Z, I suspected that it is a Hadith.

Comment: @ahmad nazeem, If you locate the exact source, please, do a favour, kindly provide an answer.

Comment: It's a daunting task but I will try, given that I get ample time to go through it all..in Sha Allah.

Comment: @Muslim As Salaamu 3laykum, i hope you are doing. Where did you hear this from? Are you 100% sure that this is a hadith?

Comment: Wa alaikum assalam. I am not sure. I suspected it is Hadith.

Comment: @ahmadnazeem do you have any more information? I mean who the imam was etc. searching based on an English description is highly faulty and meaningless, I've tried to check for some specific keywords, but had no positive finding in that book.

Comment: @Medi1Saif i recall about this story because i have heard this a long time ago from a teacher of mine. during my recent research i have come across this many times, but i am still not able to pinpoint the exact reference yet, whats sure about is it's reported by Al-Alusi (R). here is the YouTube link to the video where a speaker tells the same story. the story starts around 1.18 sec - https://youtu.be/1-oGtx5JxKc

Comment: @ahmad nazeem, this is the story I heard. There are some issues to discuss regarding it. But first the original source must be found.